# How to pass state from one react native screen to another

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two independent screen

1. Login Screen
2. DashBoard

Now on the login screen i store the requested API data inside the state (this.state.data) and that stored data I want to show on the dashboard screen for example the name or the age or the country or whatever. Now how do I sync both of these screens, I am using React Navigation 2.0

Answer (score 3):

On success of a login request you need to change your current component to the Dashboard component, which -

Can be done in two ways

1. If you are replacing the component then you can call `<Dashboard data={this.state.data} />` and fetch it in your Dashboard screen as `this.props.data`
2. If you are navigating to the component, you can do it via `this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard', { data: this.state.data });` and then in your Dashboard component you can fetch it via `this.props.navigation.state.params.data`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a small project, you can do this via props, as explained by [@Aseem Upadhyay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5120092/aseem-upadhyay)

But note that this method becomes ineffective as your project grows. Imagine that you have multiple screens, distributed in a hierarchy, in which one daughter screen needs to pass data to another, which is on a different node. To do this via props, it would be necessary for the parent component to pass these values ​​to both screens. This form is very difficult to manage.

The ideal way to do this is through redux. With it, you create a shared store of variables, so you can access them anywhere in the application. The following link demonstrates how to configure redux in your project.
https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29

It is recommended to use redux for variables that need to be shared. If you have only local component variables, then you do not need to use it.

I hope this can help you in your projects.

Hugs!

Comment: I am new to React native, So i am still learning the basics of RN only ..... I will see if i get the time to learn redux.... the brief introduction you have given is very very helpful thanks bro, hugs!